# Monitor static object in heap

Tags: java, heap-memory, heap-dump

This is a general question, is there any way I can view the value of a public static object value in heap dump ?

Sincere thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: That would depend on the language. C will give you an object's memory address and let you access addresses directly, while Java will not.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dementis. This is about Java